# Getting Connection Id of the client from a Controller class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-server, signalr

I am building a chat application in MVC using signalR. I know how to get the client's ConnectionID from the Hub. 
But is it possible to get the same connectionID from a Controller?

I tried using HttpContext and OwinContext but from the several properties I couldn't find the ConnectionId property. Not even in the Request property of the HttpContext.

Can anyone give any idea?

In this post_ [How to obtain connection ID of signalR client on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908620/how-to-obtain-connection-id-of-signalr-client-on-the-server-side)

_the first answer advises you to have the Hub invoke the external method.

I am aware of the design where we keep a Dictionary that maps each userId to several ConnectionIds for several devices.

But Let's say there is a UserController which has a LogIn and LogOut Action. It would be easier if I could get the connectionId of the user who just logged in. Then I would simply get its userID from the DbContext and store it the previously mentioned Dictionary, which can later be used by the Hub.

Comment: You can get it on the client side and then send the value to the controller. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908620/how-to-obtain-connection-id-of-signalr-client-on-the-server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.connection.hub.id` within your JavaScript on the client side and `Context.connectionId` within your SignalR hub ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubcallercontext.connectionid(v=vs.118).aspx)) to get the connection ID of the user.

You can then do whatever you want with it, you could post it from the client side via AJAX to a controller or from the server side to your client from your SignalR hub.

If you need to retrieve the SignalR connection ID that hasn't already been persisted in some form (sessions, database) from within a controller - that sounds like a code smell to me.

You should be performing anything that you need to do from within your SignalR hub.  Whether it be some processing, or sending your client ID to the database for later use by your controller.

If the problem is that the code you want to execute already exists within your Controller and you want to use that and you don't want it to exist in two places, you should move this code into a service layer (business layer) and add it as a dependency to your Controller and to your SignalR hub.

In terms of mapping your connection ID to the logged in user, this is performed as default functionality when you establish a connection to a SignalR hub, as long as your user is already logged in.

Within the hubs, you can get the ID of the user that makes the call to your hub and return a message back to them by their username or user id:

```
public MyHub : Hub
{
    public void FirstMethod()
    {
        // Invoke method to the current caller to the hub
        Clients.Client(connectionId).clientMethod();
    }

    public void SecondMethod()
    {
        // Get user id of the person making the call
        var userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        // Invoke method on the client side
        Clients.User(userId).clientMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to log in at the "index.cshtml" page. Then I move to "chat.cshtml" page to start chatting. Now in this case how can I map my UserID to my connectionID ? 
My idea was since Login is done by controllers so it would be kind of meaningful to add this entry <UserId, ConnectionId> in the Login Action of the containing controller(e.g. UserController) .

Comment: When you establish the connection on `chat.cshtml`, your SignalR connection is automatically assigned to the user id

Comment: yes from this post  (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections ) I learned that IUserId Provider will give me the UserId. I am trying to implement using the second method in that post(i.e. Using In Memory Storage), assuming I'll have more control on the storage of the information.

Comment: The user's connection ID would be added to the in-memory collection when the page establishes a connection to your SignalR hub, not when your user logs in through the controller.  The SignalR connections are established using JavaScript via HTTP request to the Hubs at which point a connection ID is generated.

Comment: I'd be tempted to just use SignalR as it works out of the box and determine whether you need to use the in-memory stuff.  SignalR integrates nicely with ASP.NET Identity out of the box without the need to persist connections in memory unless there is a specific requirement for it.  If you have a chat page, you just want to send messages to users that have the chat pages open, and you can do this easily using their `userid`, even if they have multiple pages open, you won't need to worry about connection Ids.

Comment: That somewhat helps me. Thanks